# Can I put steam humidifier nozzle above the AC coils

Tags: furnace, humidifier, steam

I'm trying to understand how the AC coils drain the condensation.
I have installed a steam humidifier and connected to the top plenum above the furnace and AC coils.

[image: Utility room with humidifier, AC & Furnace labeled]

My worries are if the steam will start to condense and drip down it might end up dripping inside the furnace coils. But there are also the AC coils as you can see in the picture. The AC coils have their own drainage. Will this drainage take care of the steam humidifier's condensation dripping or will it go through and down to the furnace coils?

Basically, my question is:
**Is it OK to have this humidifier connected like this on top of the plenum?**

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

Is the steam introduction guaranteed to always be a gas (no liquid at all) and only being introduced when the heater and fan are on? And even better if the steam turns off before the end of the fan cycle to try to dry any wet spots.

You should inspect the AC coil area and see how large the condensate collection pan is. It probably will NOT be large enough (meaning it is just underneath the AC coil plus a 0.5 inch or so). It is likely any steam condensate (or non-steam water) would drip down more towards the center of the plenum based on the pic (therefore ending up where you don't want it).

You definitely want to avoid leaving any moisture rich environment to avoid things that grow, like mold.

Comment: Is the mold the only problem? I have the UV lamp inside. What about if water drips on the furnace coils? Could that crack the heat exchanger? I will have the humidifier running only when the fan is on. But for the steam it takes some time to stop after the fan is off.

Comment: @Grasper If it's an updraft furnace, the blower fan might be damaged. Yes, it could crack the heat exchanger, especially if fan doesn't run long enough to cool them down and also if air flow doesn't keep carrying away any liquid water. But cracking is the short term trouble, corrosion might be a long term trouble (and more insidious because of CO poisoning). If it were me, I'd be troubled by steam running longer than the fan - it's very likely to condense on the insides of the ducting too. I have no experience with UV lamp mitigation so I don't know how effective it would be in this situation.

Comment: So what can I do? I have flex ducts coming out from all sides. Do I need to create a trunk away from the plenum? I worry the humidifier won't reach. It will need to be moved.

Comment: @Grasper To use your current physical setup, it might be sufficient to tie the steam control into when the furnace burner is on AND the blower fan is on. This would be your best bet to keep liquid water at bay in the system. You may need to contact the steam unit's manufacturer for advice on how to do this. I would also suggest that if there's a steam flow control that you start out at the minimum setting and inspect the system for signs of moisture. Also repeat the inspection during winter's coldest days, if that influences the utility room's ambient temp.